# Kubectl delete PDB <pdbname> gets recreated

Tags: kubernetes, calico

I have an issue where I need to delete a calico-typha poddisruption budget resource and it keeps on respawning.

So far I've tried

- `kubectl delete pdb calico-typha`
- `kubectl delete pdb calico-typha --grace-period=0 --force`
- I even edit it `kubectl edit pdb calico-typha` and inside I change `blockOwnerDelete` set to false saved it, checked the pdb -oyaml but it has not changed.. tried delete again, no luck.
- edit `minAvailable` set to 3, saved it. issue kubectl get pdb -owide but `AllowedDisruption` is still 0

It seems like the pdb is respawning depite what i do, and it cannot be edited as well..

I know that pods can have replicaset so I would understand if this is a pod but it's not and since it's a PDB and I could not find a documentation where you can set a replicaset for PDB.

Thanks!!

Comment: The other thing I tried is to issue kubectl patch but also did not work. It seems like the pdb resource is resiliently broken.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up restarting the entire cluster. After the restart, the pdb's AllowedDisruption is set to 1 so then I could continue my upgrade.